# "Can not load openssl" on push to Bluemix

Tags: ruby-on-rails, openssl, push, ibm-cloud

Up till a couple of weeks a go I was able to push my RoRs apps to Bluemix no problem but today I am encountering an error when bundler attempts to run during migration.

I use `cf push appname -c "bundle exec rake db:migrate"` command, and it has worked fine in the past. What happens today...

> "Can not load openssl"...."failed to install gems via bundler"

Bundler works fine locally. It's only when I try push the app it fails. Is anyone else having this difficulty? The last time I pushed the app was a couple of weeks back, worked fine. I have not changed anything since. I'm totally at a loss. I have been looking at suggestions online but the solutions all assume bundler does not run locally (which in my case it does).

I tried changing the rubygems source in my gemfile back and forward between "http" and "https" but no luck.

Some code: Gemfile

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

ruby '2.1.0'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.1'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record

gem 'ibm_db'

gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.3.13'

#gem 'sqlite3'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby


# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

gem 'devise'

gem 'activeadmin', '~> 1.0.0.pre1'

gem 'cancancan'

gem 'rolify'

gem 'listjs-rails'

gem 'ransack'

gem 'simple_form', '~> 3.1.1'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.5'

gem 'kaminari', '~> 0.16.1'

gem 'bootstrap-kaminari-views'
# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'

  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
end
```

Rakefile:

```
require File.expand_path('../config/application', __FILE__)

    namespace :cf do
        desc "Only run on the first application instance"
        task :on_first_instance do
            instance_index = JSON.parse(ENV["VCAP_APPLICATION"])["instance_index"] rescue nil
        exit(0) unless instance_index == 0
        end
    end

    Rails.application.load_tasks
```

Config/production.rb

```
 ...   config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
      config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

      # Enable Rack::Cache to put a simple HTTP cache in front of your application
      # Add `rack-cache` to your Gemfile before enabling this.
      # For large-scale production use, consider using a caching reverse proxy like
      # NGINX, varnish or squid.
      # config.action_dispatch.rack_cache = true

      # Disable serving static files from the `/public` folder by default since
      # Apache or NGINX already handles this.
      config.serve_static_files = true

      # Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
      config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
      # config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

      # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
      config.assets.compile = true

      # Asset digests allow you to set far-future HTTP expiration dates on all assets,
      # yet still be able to expire them through the digest params.
      config.assets.digest = true
```

Any ideas? Would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the full error message/stack trace. Also can you confirm openssl is installed on your VM.

Comment: ***`Plus One`*** because you actually provided relevant code with the configuration problem.

Comment: Hi, what is the configuration problem? I tried on two separate machines, same issue. Pulling my hair out! Thanks.

Comment: jww can you indicate where the configuration problem is? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

@penner, thanks for your response

```
       downloading and untarring DB2 CLI driver....
       setting DB2 ODBC driver ENV variables
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4
       Could not load OpenSSL.
       You must recompile Ruby with OpenSSL support or change the sources in your
       Gemfile from 'https' to 'http'. Instructions for compiling with OpenSSL using
       RVM are available at http://rvm.io/packages/openssl.
       Bundler Output:
       Could not load OpenSSL.
       You must recompile Ruby with OpenSSL support or change the sources in your
       Gemfile from 'https' to 'http'. Instructions for compiling with OpenSSL using
       RVM are available at http://rvm.io/packages/openssl.
 !
 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
 !
Staging failed: Buildpack compilation step failed

FAILED
BuildpackCompileFailed
```

Error. I would have thought the fact bundler works fine locally indicates openssl is installed? I know the files are there. I am using Windows. Is there a command I can use to check. Thanks.

In fact I can go further because I tried it on a different machine - same result. This might not be a local problem I was thinking.

Comment: The code is executing on the VM, not your local machine when it fails right? I think the problem is definitely on your VM. If you read there error, it talks about re-installing ruby with openssl. Have you looked at this link: http://rvm.io/packages/openssl - Should od this on your VM.

Comment: Thanks, I'm getting in to an awful mess trying to sort this. What is the best solution for Windows do you know?

Comment: I still don't know what to do. I deleted all my Ruby versions and Rails and reinstalled the whole lot and I have the same issue.

What I don't get is how it's the same on two different machines. If there was an error locally this would only affect my computer surely? There must be a problem in my code?

Which is odd because it was working perfectly last week.

Comment: @Bill Wentworth, sorry - I moved it. Thanks.